# Regex.Replace to put NONE between comma and remove last multiple comma

Tags: c#, regex

I have column with following value:

OK,,A,B,INSERV,OOS,,

and I'd like to get following result with Regex.Replace (field,"replace pattern") so if there is double comma between string then put NONE between comma
and remove last multiple comma:

OK,NONE,A,B,INSERV,OOS

thanks,
S

Comment: I  can get rid off multiple comma but it doesn't solve the issue with putting NONE: Regex.Replace (field,",{{2,}}",",") so I need something different.

Comment: It looks like you are using C#? Why not just use `field.TrimEnd(',')` to get rid of the trailing commas instead of using an expensive regex?

Comment: Also, do you want just ONE 'NONE' entry, if there are multiple commas?

Comment: Pattern replacement isn't the best tool for this. If this string came from a list or array, simply remove the empty strings from it. If it really began as a string, convert it to a list by splitting on `,` then remove the empty strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need at least two replace calls, one for the trailing commas and one for the commas in the middle:

```js
var input = 'OK,,,A,B,INSERV,OOS,,';
input = input.replace(/,*$/, ''); // remove trailing commas
input = input.replace(/,(?=,)/g, ',NONE'); // add NONE
console.log(input);

input = 'OK,,,A,B,INSERV,OOS,,';
input = input.replace(/,*$/, ''); // remove trailing commas
input = input.replace(/,{2,}/g, ',NONE,'); // add NONE
console.log(input);
```

First, we should remove the trailing commas, to not get any 'NONE' entries there. Then, we check for a comma, followed by a lookahead assertion matching a comma. I used the lookahead to get the regex working even when multiple commas are present (see example).

I've added two possible routes, one puts 'NONE' between all commas, the other reduces any number of commas to just ONE 'NONE' entry.

The C# syntax would be

```
var input = "OK,,,A,B,INSERV,OOS,,";
input = input.TrimEnd(',');
input = Regex.Replace(input, ",(?=,)", ",NONE"); // add NONE
input.Dump();

input = "OK,,,A,B,INSERV,OOS,,";
input = input.TrimEnd(',');
input = Regex.Replace(input, ",{2,}", ",NONE,"); // add NONE
input.Dump();
```

Comment: thanks Christoph for answer, but how I can adopt your code to Regex.Replace (field,"replace pattern")

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: C# is integrated to application and I use something like this in expression Regex.Replace (field,",{{2,}}",",")

Comment: another example I can use to replace multi hyphens with single: Regex.Replace (field_name, "\?{{1,}}","-")

Comment: I see, thanks, let me test your updated codes for C#

Comment: 2 Christoph Herold: I tested, all looks good except this one - input.TrimEnd(','); still leaves comma at the end - OK,NONE,A,B,INSERV,OOS,

Comment: Strange. Well, instead of using the `.TrimEnd(...)` you can revert to the Regex: `input = Regex.Replace(input, ",+$", "");` to remove the trailing commas.

Comment: actually this one does the job: input =  Regex.Replace(input, ",*$", ",");
input = Regex.Replace(input, ",(?=,)", ",NONE"). OK, this one the same as your previous codes. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You're very welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer as *the* answer to your question.

Comment: @ Christoph Herold: one more thing, can you advice, in case of input = ",,A,B,INSERV,OOS,," where first one is empty how I can achieve result: "NONE,NONE,A,B,INSERV,OOS", thanks?

Comment: Replace a comma at the start of the string with "NONE,": `input = Regex.Replace(input, "^,", "NONE,")`. The second `NONE` should be applied by the previous regex. So, first trim the commas from the end, then replace the on at the start, then the ones in the middle.